# Group abelianization

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, intuition

I was wondering if someone could give me an intuitive interpretation of what we have done after abelianizing a group.

I know what formal definition is: once we have our group $G$ given, we take a quotient by the commutator subgroup $[G,G]$, where $[G,G]$ is the unique smallest normal subgroup $N$ such that $G/N$ is abelian.

But who guarantees that this is abelian?

Also I was wondering why is this so helpful if in fact we get weaker (poorer) group than the first one.

Comment: It is the "adjoint thing" to forgetting that a group is Abelian. There is, in some precise sense, no better way to "make" a non-Abelian group Abelian.

Comment: No, the commutator is not "the unique smallest normal subgroup", whatever this means. It is though the minimal normal subgroup such that the quotient is *abelian* ...

Comment: The smallest normal subgroup is $\{e\}$, not the commutator.

Comment: $[G, G]$ is the unique smallest normal subgroup $N$ *such that $G/N$ is abelian*.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Let's say I have a nonabelian group $G$, and I want to "make it abelian". Intuitively, that means that whenever $g,h\in G$, I want $gh$ to be the same as $hg$.

Note that one particular case is that I'll want every element of the form $ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$ to be the identity. Interestingly, this is *all* that I need to do! If $ghg^{-1}h^{-1}=e$ for all $g, h\in G$, then $G$ is abelian: $$ghg^{-1}h^{-1}=e\implies ghg^{-1}=h\implies gh=hg.$$ So this tells us:

> In order to "make $G$ abelian," it's enough to "make every commutator trivial." And, conversely, if I "make $G$ abelian" I will "make every commutator trivial" - so these are the same task.

Now this suggests a thing to do: look at the **quotient group** gotten by modding out by the commutator subgroup! Intuitively, this should be the group which is the "abelian version" of $G$. Of course, this hinges on the commutator subgroup being *normal* . . .

. . . which it is! So that's nice.

---

Now we want to *check that everything worked properly*. Let's say $a, b\in G/Comm(G)$. Pick representatives $g, h$ of $a, b$ respectively (remember that $a, b$ are *equivalence classes* of elements of $G$). Now we have $$gh=hg(g^{-1}h^{-1}gh),$$ and $hg(g^{-1}h^{-1}gh)\equiv hg$ in the quotient group (since their difference is a commutator); so $gh$ - which is a representative of $ab$ - is equivalent in the quotient group to $hg$ - which is a representative of $ba$. So $ab=ba$.

---

You separately asked

> Why is this so helpful if in fact we get weaker (poorer) group than the first one?

Well, this is a general fact about mathematical structures - just because one structure is "smaller than" another doesn't mean it's less interesting, and indeed the quotients and substructures of a given structure can be extremely useful in analyzing it. Moreover, specific quotient constructions like the abelianization show up in other contexts; a good example of this is the fact that *the first homology group is the commutative version of the fundamental group* (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1949774/the-first-homology-group-is-the-abelianization-of-the-fundamental-group) for details).

And there are contexts where we have a natural algebraic structure, but we're only interested (for the moment) in certain aspects of it. Sometimes, for instance, for a particular context we may only be interested in the *non-torsion* part of a group. (Emphasis on **sometimes**, by the way; other times, [the torsion part is really important!](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22583/why-torsion-is-important-in-cohomology)). Basically, "truncating" a mathematical structure lets you "focus" on the behavior that you care about. Sometimes this is a thing you want to do. Sometimes it's not.

Comment: Nice answer.  +1

Comment: Thank you very much for this profound answer. So, in a sense of fundamental groups, each time we want to get from pi_1(X, x_0) to pi_1(X, x_0) - abelinized, we just take the quotient map and that's it? If I understood well..

Comment: That's a really beautiful answer. Had you also spoken about how abelianization relating to the fundamental group interprets in our geometric intution, the answer could become even more complete.